# Why can't I compile USB Proxy on my Beaglebone?

Tags: compiler-errors, beagleboneblack

I am trying to build the [USB Proxy](https://github.com/dominicgs/USBProxy) on my Beaglebone Black, but I get this error:
`error: 'libusb_hotplug_callback_handle' does not name a type`

Given the same source code, I can compile on my Linux Mint and Ubuntu machines without issues, so I'm guessing something is missing on my BB Black setup, but can't figure out what it is.

Compile log:

```
> root@beaglebone:/home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/build#
> cmake ..
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Looking for include file pthread.h
> -- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
> -- Looking for pthread_create
> -- Looking for pthread_create - not found.
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
> -- Found Threads: TRUE  
> -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
> -- checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
> --   found libusb-1.0, version 1.0.11
> -- Found LIBUSB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libusb-1.0.so  
> -- Found LORCON: /usr/local/lib/liborcon2.so  
> -- Pcap include dirs set to /usr/include
> -- Pcap library set to  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcap.so
> -- Looking for pcap_version
> -- Looking for pcap_version - found
> -- Looking for pcap_open_dead
> -- Looking for pcap_open_dead - found
> -- Looking for pcap_freecode
> -- Looking for pcap_freecode - found
> -- Looking for pcap_breakloop
> -- Looking for pcap_breakloop - found
> -- Looking for pcap_create
> -- Looking for pcap_create - found
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_name_to_val
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_name_to_val - found
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_val_to_description
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_val_to_description - found
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_val_to_name
> -- Looking for pcap_datalink_val_to_name - found
> -- Looking for pcap_findalldevs
> -- Looking for pcap_findalldevs - found
> -- Looking for pcap_free_datalinks
> -- Looking for pcap_free_datalinks - found
> -- Looking for pcap_get_selectable_fd
> -- Looking for pcap_get_selectable_fd - found
> -- Looking for pcap_lib_version
> -- Looking for pcap_lib_version - found
> -- Looking for pcap_list_datalinks
> -- Looking for pcap_list_datalinks - found
> -- Looking for pcap_set_datalink
> -- Looking for pcap_set_datalink - found
> -- Looking for pcap_open
> -- Looking for pcap_open - not found
> -- Looking for pcap_findalldevs_ex
> -- Looking for pcap_findalldevs_ex - not found
> -- Looking for pcap_createsrcstr
> -- Looking for pcap_createsrcstr - not found
> -- Found PCAP: /usr/include  
> -- Configuring done
> -- Generating done
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/build
> root@beaglebone:/home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/build# make
> Scanning dependencies of target USBProxy [  2%] Building CXX object
> lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/ConfigParser.cpp.o [  5%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Criteria.cpp.o [  7%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/DeviceQualifier.cpp.o [ 10%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/HexString.cpp.o [ 12%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Interface.cpp.o [ 15%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Manager.cpp.o [ 17%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/RelayReader.cpp.o [
> 20%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/TCP_Helper.cpp.o
> [ 22%] Building CXX object
> lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Configuration.cpp.o [ 25%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Device.cpp.o [ 27%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Endpoint.cpp.o [ 30%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/HID.cpp.o [ 32%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/InterfaceGroup.cpp.o [ 35%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/Injector.cpp.o [ 37%]
> Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/PacketFilter.cpp.o [
> 40%] Building CXX object
> lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/PluginManager.cpp.o [ 42%] Building CXX
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/RelayWriter.cpp.o [ 45%] Building
> CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/USBString.cpp.o [ 47%] Building
> C object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/FDInfo.c.o [ 50%] Building C
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/get_tid.c.o [ 52%] Building C
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/HaltSignal.c.o [ 55%] Building C
> object lib/CMakeFiles/USBProxy.dir/mqueue_helpers.c.o Linking CXX
> shared library libUSBProxy.so [ 55%] Built target USBProxy Scanning
> dependencies of target DeviceProxy_LibUSB [ 57%] Building CXX object
> Plugins/Devices/CMakeFiles/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.dir/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp.o
> In file included from
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:28:0:
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.h:38:2:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_callback_handle' does not name a type
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:40:79:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_event' has not been declared
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:
> In constructor 'DeviceProxy_LibUSB::DeviceProxy_LibUSB(int, int,
> bool)':
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:65:2:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:
> In constructor
> 'DeviceProxy_LibUSB::DeviceProxy_LibUSB(ConfigParser*)':
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:99:2:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:
> In destructor 'virtual DeviceProxy_LibUSB::~DeviceProxy_LibUSB()':
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:111:17:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:112:63:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_deregister_callback' was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:
> In member function 'int DeviceProxy_LibUSB::connect(int, int, bool)':
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:205:56:
> error: 'libusb_set_auto_detach_kernel_driver' was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:228:7:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:230:51:
> error: 'LIBUSB_HOTPLUG_EVENT_DEVICE_ARRIVED' was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:230:89:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_flag' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:230:209:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_register_callback' was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:
> In member function 'virtual void DeviceProxy_LibUSB::disconnect()':
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:246:17:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:247:63:
> error: 'libusb_hotplug_deregister_callback' was not declared in this
> scope
> /home/debian/Downloads/USBProxy-master/src/Plugins/Devices/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp:249:2:
> error: 'callback_handle' was not declared in this scope make[2]: ***
> [Plugins/Devices/CMakeFiles/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.dir/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.cpp.o]
> Error 1 make[1]: ***
> [Plugins/Devices/CMakeFiles/DeviceProxy_LibUSB.dir/all] Error 2 make:
> *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a newer version of libusb. I had exactly the same error- compiling the latest version of libusb from source and `make install`ing it fixed this problem.